# A site always redirects to "http://www.2fun.in/gag/5185" even when I am on a page...How do I stop this?

Tags: url, redirect, browser

How can I stop this hijacking of my page by this unwarranted page...http://www.2fun.in/gag/5185...on my site ?

Answer (score 0):

Same goes to me before this.. I'm using mozilla firefox, and this problem only happen when I use firefox..

The only one way I used to solve,, uninstall, then re-install back firefox..

SOLVED..working for me... let try..!

Comment: sorry mate. I did that also. Still its not working in my one.